# How to post List of List from view to Controller in asp .net Core?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to Post List of data by Ajax to asp .net controller.

```js
 var DataList = {
                motherName: $("#motherName").val(),
                parentName: parentName,
                pieceName: pieceName,
                pieceFeatures: pieceFeatures,
                //pieceFeaturesList: null,
                featureValueLists: featureValueLists
            };

           

            JQAjax("Post", "Add_KbyFeatures",
                DataList , function (data) {
                    if (data)
                        if (data.isSuccess) {

                            ////
                        }
                });
```

featureValueLists is a list.

Comment: Are you going to post the list after `window.onload` or if you clicked some `button`?

Comment: clicked some button

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#your_button_id").on('click', function() { //if your button got clicked. This button going to get triggered
  if($("#your_button_id").on(':clicked')) {
    $.ajax({
      url: //Your URL to asp.net controller,
      type: "GET", //GET means getting the data, POST saving the data
      data: {
        motherName: $("#motherName").val(),
        parentName: parentName,
        pieceName: pieceName,
        pieceFeatures: pieceFeatures,
        //pieceFeaturesList: null,
        featureValueLists: featureValueLists
      }, //This is where you get the value for your controller
      dataType: "html", //dataType is the type if your result should be json or html
      success: function(result) { //if the controller gets the data and its not null or undefined it will throw it here
        $("your_result_show").html(result) //after the controller gets your data. The gathered data will show here
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo, you can refer to it:

Thing:

```
 public class Thing
    {
        public string parentName { get; set; }
        public string pieceName { get; set; }
        public string pieceFeatures { get; set; }
        
    }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
           public IActionResult Index()
           {
               return View();
           }
            [HttpPost]
            public void PassThings(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
            {
                // do stuff with things here...
            }
    }
```

Index view:

```
<input type="button"  id="btnProjectSave" name="but1" class="btn btn-default" value ="OnPostProjectSubmit">
<div  id="result">
    
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
$(function() {
    $("#btnProjectSave").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var things = [
            {  
                parentName: 'parentName',
                pieceName: 'pieceName',
                pieceFeatures: 'pieceFeatures',//do your staff...
             },
            
        ];
        $.post('@Url.Action("PassThings")', { things: things },
            function() {
                $('#result').html('"PassThings()" successfully called.');
            });
    });
});
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Hassan Rasouli, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.